# Replace img tags from headless cms with Next Image component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, headless

I am working on a headless wordpress marketing/commerce app with Nextjs (hosted on vercel) and would like to parse incoming content bodies to conditionally replace `img` tags therein using the Next/Image `Image` component. If anyone has any ideas on how to go about hot-swapping Image for img so that the images are rendered as WebP and not png that would be immensely appreciated.

- Here is my Page Template Component used to render 9 top-level pages currently

```
import css from './page-template.module.css';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { Fallback, AtomicImage } from '../UI';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {
  PageIdType,
  useParentPageQuery,
  ParentPageQuery
} from '@/graphql/graphql';
import parser, { DOMNode, HTMLReactParserOptions } from 'html-react-parser';
import { Element, Node } from 'domhandler/lib/node';
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloError as ApolloErrorProps } from '@apollo/client';

export interface PageTemplateProps {
  className?: string;
  topLevelPage: ParentPageQuery['page'];
}

const dynamicProps = {
  loading: () => <Fallback />
};

const ApolloError = dynamic<{ error: ApolloErrorProps }>(
  async () => import('../UI/ApolloError'),
  dynamicProps
);

const PageTemplate = ({ className, topLevelPage }: PageTemplateProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const paths = router.query ? (router.query.paths as string) : '/';
  console.log(JSON.stringify(paths, null, 2));
  const { data, loading, error } = useParentPageQuery({
    variables: {
      idType: PageIdType.URI,
      id: encodeURIComponent(paths)
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  });

  topLevelPage = data != null && data.page != null ? data.page : undefined;

  const options: HTMLReactParserOptions = {
    replace: (domNode: DOMNode) => {
      if (
        domNode instanceof Node && domNode.type
          ? domNode.type.replace('img', 'Image')
          : domNode.type
      ) {
        return domNode;
      }
      return domNode.cloneNode();
    }
  };
  const value = parser(`${topLevelPage?.content}`, options);
  const ele = value;

  const htmlToReact = (x: string) =>
    parser(x, {
      replace: (domNode: DOMNode) => {
        if (domNode instanceof Element && domNode.attribs) {
          return domNode.attribs;
        } else {
          return domNode.cloneNode();
        }
      }
    });
  console.log(
    htmlToReact(
      `${
        topLevelPage?.content?.includes(`img`)
          ? topLevelPage.content.replace('img', 'Image')
          : topLevelPage?.content
      }`
    )
  );
  // const x = createElement(
  //   topLevelPage?.content ? topLevelPage.content : `${topLevelPage?.content}`
  // )
  // const GenesisElement = React.createElement(topLevelPage!.content as string);
  return (
    <>
      {error ? (
        <ApolloError error={error} />
      ) : loading && !error ? (
        <Fallback />
      ) : (
        <>
          {topLevelPage &&
          topLevelPage.content &&
          topLevelPage.title &&
          topLevelPage.featuredImage ? (
            <>
              <div
                className={cn(
                  'overflow-hidden select-none font-sans',
                  className
                )}>
                <div className='relative max-w-8xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
                  <div className='hidden lg:block bg-blue-900 absolute top-0 bottom-0 left-3/4 w-screen'></div>
                  <div className='mx-auto text-base max-w-7xl lg:grid lg:grid-cols-5 lg:gap-8 lg:max-w-none'>
                    <div className='lg:col-span-3 '>
                      <h2 className='text-5xl font-sans text-blue-800 font-semibold tracking-tighter uppercase'>
                        <div
                          className={cn(
                            css.title,
                            'capitalize font-sans transform-translate transform-gpu mt-5 ml-5'
                          )}>
                          {parser(topLevelPage.title).toString()}
                        </div>
                      </h2>
                      <div className=' text-justify justify-items-stretch justify-around text-base leading-normal font-medium tracking-tight sm:text-lg duration-300 transition-colors'>
                        <div className={cn(css.p)}>
                          {htmlToReact(
                            `${
                              topLevelPage?.content?.includes(`img`)
                                ? topLevelPage.content.replace('img', 'Image')
                                : topLevelPage?.content
                            }`
                          )}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='mt-8 lg:grid lg:col-span-2 lg:gap-8'>
                      <div className='relative lg:row-start-1 lg:col-start-2'>
                        <svg
                          className='hidden lg:block absolute top-0 right-0 -mt-20 -mr-20'
                          width='404'
                          height='384'
                          fill='none'
                          viewBox='0 0 404 384'
                          aria-hidden='true'>
                          <defs>
                            <pattern
                              id='de316486-4a29-4312-bdfc-fbce2132a2c1'
                              x='0'
                              y='0'
                              width='20'
                              height='20'
                              patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
                              <rect
                                x='0'
                                y='0'
                                width='4'
                                height='4'
                                className='text-gray-50'
                                fill='rgba(249, 250, 251,1)'
                              />
                            </pattern>
                          </defs>
                          <rect
                            width='404'
                            height='384'
                            fill='#rgba(249, 250, 251,1)'
                          />
                        </svg>
                        <div className='relative text-base mx-auto max-w-prose lg:max-w-none'>
                          <figure>
                            <div className='aspect-w-12 aspect-h-7 lg:aspect-none bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-75 rounded-full p-4'>
                              <AtomicImage
                                className='rounded-lg shadow-lg object-cover object-center'
                                width={500}
                                aria-orientation='vertical'
                                height={500}
                                src={
                                  topLevelPage.featuredImage.node?.sourceUrl
                                    ? topLevelPage.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl
                                    : 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2715d942950e7c4c4672dcb984c52e84?s=96&d=mm&r=pg'
                                }
                              />
                            </div>
                            <figcaption className='flex text-sm text-gray-100'>
                              <svg
                                className='flex-none w-6 h-6 text-blue-700'
                                stroke='#000000'
                                strokeWidth='1'
                                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                                fill=''
                                aria-hidden='true'>
                                <path
                                  fillRule='evenodd'
                                  d='M4 5a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-1.586a1 1 0 01-.707-.293l-1.121-1.121A2 2 0 0011.172 3H8.828a2 2 0 00-1.414.586L6.293 4.707A1 1 0 015.586 5H4zm6 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6z'
                                  clipRule='evenodd'
                                  fill='text-blue-700'
                                />
                              </svg>
                              <span className='ml-2 text-gray-600 font-medium'>
                                {topLevelPage.title}
                              </span>
                            </figcaption>
                          </figure>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PageTemplate;
```

I have tried using

```
 const htmlToReact = (x: string) =>
    parser(x, {
      replace: (domNode: DOMNode) => {
        if (domNode instanceof Element && domNode.attribs) {
          return domNode.attribs;
        } else {
          return domNode.cloneNode();
        }
      }
    });
  console.log(
    htmlToReact(
      `${
        topLevelPage?.content?.includes(`img`)
          ? topLevelPage?.content?.replace('img', 'Image')
          : topLevelPage?.content
      }`
    )
  );
```

Which, when console logged, has the following shape:

```
[
  '\n',
  {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: 'div',
    key: '1',
    ref: null,
    props: {
      className: 'wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-columns gpb-altitude-section-text-image-columns-dark gb-layout-columns-2 gb-2-col-equal has-eso-white-background-color gb-columns-center alignfull',
      style: [Object],
      children: [Object]
    },
    _owner: null,
    _store: {}
  },
  '\n'
]
```

Expanding the above:

```
[
  "\n",
  {
    "type": "div",
    "key": "1",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "className": "wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-columns gpb-altitude-section-text-image-columns-dark gb-layout-columns-2 gb-2-col-equal has-eso-white-background-color gb-columns-center alignfull",
      "style": {
        "paddingTop": "3em",
        "paddingRight": "1em",
        "paddingBottom": "3em",
        "paddingLeft": "1em"
      },
      "children": {
        "type": "div",
        "key": null,
        "ref": null,
        "props": {
          "className": "gb-layout-column-wrap gb-block-layout-column-gap-2 gb-is-responsive-column",
          "style": {
            "maxWidth": "1200px"
          },
          "children": [
            "\n",
            {
              "type": "div",
              "key": "1",
              "ref": null,
              "props": {
                "className": "wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-column gb-block-layout-column gb-is-vertically-aligned-top",
                "children": {
                  "type": "div",
                  "key": null,
                  "ref": null,
                  "props": {
                    "className": "gb-block-layout-column-inner",
                    "children": [
                      "\n",
                      {
                        "type": "h2",
                        "key": "1",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "style": {
                            "fontSize": "28px"
                          },
                          "children": "Start with Spot."
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "key": "3",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "children": "Next Gen Dermatology meets Coast-to-Coast Accessibility — Spot. AI-Powered, HIPAA-Compliant; Guaranteed to meet your Skincare needs."
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "h2",
                        "key": "5",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "style": {
                            "fontSize": "28px"
                          },
                          "children": "Create a Case."
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "key": "7",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "children": "Creating a new case on Spot is as easy as 1, 2, 3. You’re walked through a set of skin-related questions — similar to ones your doctor would ask you in person."
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "h2",
                        "key": "9",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "style": {
                            "fontSize": "28px"
                          },
                          "children": "Conquer the Unexpected"
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "key": "11",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "has-eso-black-color has-text-color",
                          "children": "Don’t put looking and feeling your best on hold for weeks if not months to get in with a specialist; conquer skin conditions as they arise from the convenience of your smart phone or computer with Spot. "
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  },
                  "_owner": null,
                  "_store": {}
                }
              },
              "_owner": null,
              "_store": {}
            },
            "\n\n\n\n",
            {
              "type": "div",
              "key": "3",
              "ref": null,
              "props": {
                "className": "wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-column gb-block-layout-column gb-is-vertically-aligned-center",
                "children": {
                  "type": "div",
                  "key": null,
                  "ref": null,
                  "props": {
                    "className": "gb-block-layout-column-inner",
                    "children": [
                      "\n",
                      {
                        "type": "figure",
                        "key": "1",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "className": "wp-block-image size-full is-style-default",
                          "children": {
                            "type": "img",
                            "key": null,
                            "ref": null,
                            "props": {
                              "loading": "lazy",
                              "width": "980",
                              "height": "980",
                              "src": "https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=980%2C980&ssl=1",
                              "alt": "",
                              "className": "wp-image-71",
                              "srcSet": "https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?w=981&ssl=1 981w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=300%2C300&ssl=1 300w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=150%2C150&ssl=1 150w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=768%2C768&ssl=1 768w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=600%2C600&ssl=1 600w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=324%2C324&ssl=1 324w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=416%2C416&ssl=1 416w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=100%2C100&ssl=1 100w",
                              "sizes": "(max-width: 980px) 100vw, 980px",
                              "data-recalc-dims": "1",
                              "children": null
                            },
                            "_owner": null,
                            "_store": {}
                          }
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n\n\n\n",
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "key": "3",
                        "ref": null,
                        "props": {
                          "children": null
                        },
                        "_owner": null,
                        "_store": {}
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  },
                  "_owner": null,
                  "_store": {}
                }
              },
              "_owner": null,
              "_store": {}
            },
            "\n"
          ]
        },
        "_owner": null,
        "_store": {}
      }
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  "\n"
]
```

Which ultimately contains:

```html
<img loading="lazy" width="980" height="980" src="https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=980%2C980&amp;ssl=1" alt="" class="wp-image-71" srcset="https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?w=981&amp;ssl=1 981w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=150%2C150&amp;ssl=1 150w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=768%2C768&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=600%2C600&amp;ssl=1 600w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=324%2C324&amp;ssl=1 324w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=416%2C416&amp;ssl=1 416w, https://i1.wp.com/cortinaai.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Spot.png?resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 100w" sizes="(max-width: 980px) 100vw, 980px" data-recalc-dims="1" />
```

Here is my top level catch-all parent pages file, [...paths].tsx

```
import { pathDeduplication } from '@/lib/path-deduplication';
import { AppLayout } from '@/components/Layout';
import { initializeApollo, addApolloState } from '@/apollo/apollo';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Fallback } from '@/components/UI';
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from '@/types/pages';
import { PageTemplate } from '@/components/PageTemplate';
import {
  GetStaticPathsContext,
  GetStaticPathsResult,
  GetStaticPropsContext,
  GetStaticPropsResult,
  InferGetStaticPropsType
} from 'next';
import {
  ParentPageDocument,
  ParentPagesDocument,
  ParentPageQuery,
  ParentPagesQuery,
  ParentPageQueryVariables,
  ParentPagesQueryVariables,
  PageIdType,
  DynamicNavDocument,
  DynamicNavQuery,
  DynamicNavQueryVariables,
  MenuNodeIdTypeEnum,
  OrderEnum,
  PostObjectsConnectionOrderbyEnum
} from '@/graphql/graphql';

export type CatchAllTopLevelPagesProps = {
  nav: DynamicNavQuery;
  pageData: ParentPageQuery;
  paths: string;
};
const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

export const getStaticPaths = async ({
  locales
}: GetStaticPathsContext): Promise<GetStaticPathsResult<ParsedUrlQuery>> => {
  const { data: parentPages } = await apolloClient.query<
    ParentPagesQuery,
    ParentPagesQueryVariables
  >({
    query: ParentPagesDocument,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    variables: {
      first: 30,
      parentIn: [null],
      field: PostObjectsConnectionOrderbyEnum.SLUG,
      order: OrderEnum.DESC
    }
  });

  return {
    paths: locales
      ? locales.reduce<string[]>((paths, locale) => {
          parentPages.pages?.edges?.forEach(page => {
            if (page?.node?.slug && !pathDeduplication.includes(page.node.slug))
              paths.push(`/${locale}/${page.node.slug}`);
          });
          return paths;
        }, [])
      : parentPages?.pages?.edges
      ? parentPages.pages.edges.map(page => `/${page?.node?.slug}`)
      : ['/'],
    fallback: false
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (
  ctx: GetStaticPropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>
): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<CatchAllTopLevelPagesProps>> => {
  const paths = ctx.params ? (ctx.params.paths as string) : '/';
  const { data: pageData } = await apolloClient.query<
    ParentPageQuery,
    ParentPageQueryVariables
  >({
    query: ParentPageDocument,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    variables: {
      id: paths[0],
      idType: PageIdType.URI
    }
  });
  const { data: nav } = await apolloClient.query<
    DynamicNavQuery,
    DynamicNavQueryVariables
  >({
    query: DynamicNavDocument,
    variables: {
      idHead: 'Header',
      idTypeHead: MenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
      idFoot: 'Footer',
      idTypeFoot: MenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  });
  return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
    props: {
      nav,
      pageData,
      paths
    },
    revalidate: 60
  });
};

export default function PathsCatchAllPage<T extends typeof getStaticProps>({
  nav,
  pageData,
  paths
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<T>) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(paths, null, 2));
  const router = useRouter();
  paths = router.query ? (router.query.paths as string) : '';

  return (
    <>
      {router.isFallback ? (
        <>
          <Fallback />
        </>
      ) : pageData ? (
        <AppLayout header={nav.Header} footer={nav.Footer}>
          {pageData && pageData.page ? (
            <PageTemplate topLevelPage={pageData.page} />
          ) : (
            <div>{'loading...'}</div>
          )}
        </AppLayout>
      ) : (
        <>{'Something went wrong...'}</>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

The image renders as a png instead of webp (intended result) for everything I've attempted so far

[link to vercel app](https://cortina-headless.vercel.app)

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#domains -- Try adding `i1.wp.com` to this. The rest of your code appears to be fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? Did the above code end up working?